# Trying to Execute Ruby Code for the first time.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Project: 
https://github.com/jmopr/job-hunter

Background:

> Took only 2 intro course on Java 7 years ago.

So I was browsing GitHub and ran across this nifty project that deals with scraping & applying for jobs on indeed.com.

The question is, how do you run it? Here is what I tried to do:

Tried to execute applier.ru I figured I was doing something wrong after getting:

/home/shap/Desktop/job-hunter-master/applier.rb:19:in `initialize': uninitialized constant JobApplier::Job (NameError)
    from /home/shap/Desktop/job-hunter-master/applier.rb:169:in`new'
    from /home/shap/Desktop/job-hunter-master/applier.rb:169:in `'

Something was missing, so looking around I found the bin folder and tried executing /bin/setup.ru but i ran into this error:

== Preparing database ==
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `database_configuration': Cannot load`Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"] (RuntimeError)

Are we supposed to generate our own database file? how would we do that?

Any help or even a push in the right path is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to generate your own database configuration. It should be stored at `config/database.yml`. It's a file that specify where's your db server, what's the name of the database and what should be the credentials to access it. Google "rails database.yml example".

Once you have that, creating your actual database is as easy as running these commands

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

There may be many-many other different obstacles on your journey of making this application run. Things that are obvious to rails devs, but arcane to total strangers. I suggest finding and completing a ruby on rails tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the help sergio. Here is the obstacle i've ran into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730353/ruby-on-rails-block-in-find-unable-to-find-field-q-capybaraelementnotfou

Answer (score 0):

This is ruby on rails project, 
after checkout you need install all required dependencies, with command

```
bundle exec install
```

Run project you can with command

```
./bin/rails server
```

If project is started successful, you can access it with browser using address http://localhost:3000

more about rails you can find there http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: The project is missing database.yml, though :)

Comment: You are both Right. I marked Sergio's answer correct because that was the initial problem I was struggling with.